# function work without class that call for function

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, function

I have two classes and a function that works with one of them

```
$('.div-image').click(function(){                    // image zoom 
    $('#image').attr("src",img_src);

    $('.div-image').attr('class','div-image-big');

});
```

and html something like:

`<div class="div-image">`
`<div id="wrapper">`
`<img id="image" src="image.jpg">`
`</div>`
`</div>`

Why after first click on the image or (div .div-image) my class div-image is changing to div-image-big. But if we click once more the function  $('.div-image').click(function(){...} will execute again. The question is why so? I don't need this behavior. I want that this function work only when class is div-image not div-image-big. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the jquery selector matches a substring of the class as well.

Comment: Instead of using `attr` look into `addClass` and `toggleClass`.

Comment: @elclanrs I tried to do this, like so: $('. div-image').addClass('div-image-big');
 $('. div-image-big').removeClass('div-image'); but this didn't work too.

Comment: If you want to listen to the event only once you can use  `one` method, otherwise you should use event delegation. the event is bound to the element not the class name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event handler is bound on the element, not the class. Which elements it is bound to is decided based on the class they have at the time that the event is bound, so changing the class later doesn't change which elements have the event handler.

If you want the event handler to react to the class, you should bind a delegate to the a parent element. That way the event bubbles to the parent element, and the delegate handler will check for the class at that moment. Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="div-image">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <img id="image" src="image.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.image-container').on('click', '.div-image' ,function(){                    // image zoom 
  $('#image').attr("src",img_src);
  $('.div-image').attr('class','div-image-big');
});
```

Comment: +1 but *"...is bound on the event"* I'm guessing you mean *"is bound on the element"*.

Comment: +1, just a note, in case that are many elements with class of `.div-image`, using `this` is better,  `$(this).attr('class','div-image-big');`

Comment: @undefined: Yes, unless you actually want to disable all of them. :)